# Django admin panel display error linked to admin.py?

Tags: django, admin, models

I have a seemingly harmless but very niggling error in my admin panel:

It erroneously produces the output "Teacherss" (double ss) and I cannot see why this occurs from my code:

**So the models.py in the teachers app is:**

```
class Teachers(models.Model):
    #this is what an album is going to be made of
    email=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    school_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**The admin.py file has this:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import Teachers 
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Teachers)
```

Any idea why this is generated in the admin panel?

MAIN
Teacherss   Add/Change

Where is the double ss coming from and how do I get rid of it!??

**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWERS**

Update: Interesting to note from the answers below that singular must be used. I did however change my code and now the following error arises:

**Error**

In admin.py
from main.models import Teacher
Import Error: cannot import name 'Teacher'

**admin.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from main.models import Teacher
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Teacher)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Teacher(models.Model):
    #this is what an album is going to be made of
    email=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    school_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

                #You need this for meta data purposes. This allows you to reference the post (otherwise it will just print the object which doesn't mean much)
                #You need this for meta data purposes. This allows you to reference the post (otherwise it will just print the object which doesn't mean much)
```

...problem resolved. I hadn't called the app in the import models (main.models had been written instead of teachers.models).

Thank you for the below answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Django expects your model to have a name in singular, i.e., `Teacher`. It also by default attaches an `s` to your model's name to show it in the admin. This can be configured from [inside your model itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural).

Answer (score 1):

The Django admin automatically adds an "s" to make the model plural. It might make sense to make your model `Teacher` instead. Otherwise you can tell the admin what you want the plural to be with:

```
class Teachers(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "teachers"
    email=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...
```